# PopUp window is still visible on screen if the MainWindow is out of focus in WPF

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a PopUp window with a popup control.There is a main window from which this PopUp is displayed. PopUp displays data after processing the query which takes time.So while the data in the PopUp is processing,if I maximise other windows then the PopUp is displayed on the other windows as well.

I have made MainWindow owner of the PopUp window in PopUpWindow.xaml.cs as:

```
this.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

and I have set "StaysOpen" property of PopUp Window to false.But still issue persists.How to stop PopUp from displaying on other window,if other windows are maximised.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to stop PopUp from displaying on other window,if other windows are maximised.

Comment: Try for `Popup` set property `Visibility` to *`Collapsed`*. Like this: `Visibility="Collapsed"` or in code: `MyPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`.

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Comment: I have corrected my mistake and accpeted the answer.Please dont misunderstand me MikroDel.

Comment: @Anatoliy I have tried Visibility="Collapsed" but it dint work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly close the popup when its owner window is deactivated, i.e. when another window gets the focus and comes to the top, using the [Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated.aspx) event:

```
    window.Deactivated += 
        (sender, args) => {
            thePopup.IsOpen = false;
        };
```

You might also want to capture the IsOpen state and restore it when the window is Activated.